# How to calculate the Summation??

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation

Can we get the formula in terms of N and k for this summation series?

$$
A=\sum_{t=0}^N\sum_{s=0}^t\sum_{r=0}^sk^rk^{s-r}k^{t-s}
$$

Comment: $ \displaystyle A=\sum_{t=0}^N\sum_{s=0}^t\sum_{r=0}^s k^t$

Comment: @MathGod, it is the answer, not a comment I hope!

Comment: @JessePFrancis: the answer is given by an explicit function of $k$ and $N$.

Comment: This is related to some (temporarily?) deleted questions regarding an ongoing contest problem to count triples of strings, none of which is a prefix of the other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$A=\sum_{t=0}^{N}\sum_{s=0}^{t}\sum_{r=0}^{s}k^t=\sum_{t=0}^N\sum_{s=0}^t (s+1)k^t = \sum_{t=0}^N \frac{(t+2)(t+1)}{2}k^t \tag{1}$$
is a partial sum for the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{(1-k)^3}$ in a neighbourhood of $k=0$.

By multiplying the RHS of $(1)$ by $(1-k)^3$ we get:

> $$ A = \frac{1}{(1-k)^3}\left(1-\binom{N+3}{2}k^{N+1}+(N+3)(N+1)k^{N+2}-\binom{N+2}{2}k^{N+3}\right).\tag{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Another way of determining the last sum is to note that if

$$S_N(k)=\frac12 \sum_{t=0}^N k^{t+2}=\frac{k^2-k^{N+3}}{2(1-k)} \tag 1$$

then upon taking two derivatives reveals that

$$S_N''(k)=\sum_{t=0}^N \frac{(t+2)(t+1)}{2}k^{t}=A \tag 2$$

Thus, taking the second derivative of the right-hand side of $(1)$, we find that

$$S_N''(k)= \frac12 \left( 2\frac{k^2-k^{N+3}}{(1-k)^3} +2\frac{2k-(N+3)k^{N+2}}{(1-k)^2} +\frac{2-(N+3)(N+2)k^{N+1}}{1-k}    \right)$$